# Что за ошибка с установкой плагина gulp-sass?

Tags: gulp, sass, scss, gulp-sass

`

```html
<pre>
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: D:\GoG GAMES\nodejs\node.exe D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\GoG GAMES\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\Пользователи\\Kot\\Рабочий стол\\Gulp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.2.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "D:\\GoG GAMES\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Пользователи\\Kot\\Рабочий стол\\Gulp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kot\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-20T17_43_18_733Z-debug.log
PS D:\Пользователи\Kot\Рабочий стол\Gulp>
</pre>
```

Comment: Can't find Python executable "python“

Comment: Ооо, я тебя в двух вопросах об этой ошибке видел, но питон 2.7 установлен, а вчера установил все возможные версии nodejs, но всё тоже:)